# near-sdk-as u256 is not implemented yet?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to implement a NEP141 Token with the assemblyscript sdk.

When I use the u256 variables from the near-sdk-as, I receive the following compilation error:

```
ERROR TS2322: Type '~lib/as-bignum/integer/u256/u256' is not assignable to type '~lib/as-bignum/integer/safe/u256/u256'.
```

Opening the u256 class in as-bignum/integer/safe dependency, I can see that the class is just a stub function with a //TODO comment.

So, my question is: should I use this class? Should I wait to use that class? Will it be defined in the future? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks!

P.s. The as-bignum version used in the near-sdk-as is the 0.2.15. I've already checked the last as-bignum version and the u256 is still just a stub.

Comment: u256 math is not supported in AssemblyScript afaik

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, u256 Is not implemented yet in near-sdk-as.